# Grails-Camel Plugin won't install or run

Tags: grails, apache-camel, grails-plugin

**Please note:** Although this question involves a lib called [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) I really think this is just a question about how modern Grails plugins work.

I am on Grails 2.4.2 here, and I am trying to use Apache Camel with Grails and found the [Grails Routing](http://grails.org/plugin/routing) plugin annd cannot even get it to install.

The directions say to install by issuing a `grails install-plugin routing`. When I do this I get:

```
grails install-plugin routing
Starting process on LT-IE-ZH/10.10.99.14
Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
......Warning 
|
Since Grails 2.3, it is no longer possible to install plugins using the install-plugin command.
Plugins must be declared in the grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file.
Example:
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ...
    plugins {
        compile ":routing:1.3.2"
    }
}
```

So I modify my `BuildConfig.groovy` like so:

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

    compile ":routing:1.3.2"

    ...lots of other stuff omitted for brevity

}
```

Then the plugin says to create routes, issue a `grails create-route <RouteName>`. So I do exactly that:

```
grails create-route OrderListener
Starting process on LT-IE-ZH/10.10.99.14
Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
|Script 'CreateRoute' not found, did you mean:
    1) CreateFilters
    2) CreatePom
    3) CreateApp_
    4) CreateController
    5) CreateHibernateCfgXml
Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:
```

**What is going on here?!?** How do I install/use this plugin?!? Am I losing my mind, or does this plugin simply not work?

---

**Update**

I run `grails clean-all`, then `grails refresh-dependencies` then `grails create-route OrderListener` and I get:

```
Loading Grails 2.4.2
.
|Environment set to development
.....Error 
|
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: CreateRoute.createArtifact() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Error |
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Error |

<huge stacktrace omitted>

Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
Error |
... 68 more
```

Comment: run `clean` and `compile` then try using the plugin.

Comment: Just wondering why you want to configure your routes in gradle, rather than the java DSL, or in xml?

Comment: Can you try `grails clean-all` and `grails refresh-dependencies` before `create-route`

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore and mehmood, however please see my update, as cleaning and refreshing dependencies only made things **worse**. As for vikingstever, sorry but this has absolutely nothing to do with Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you make a change in `BuildConfig.groovy` be sure to run `grails compile` to trigger dependency resolution, which will download new and updated plugins and jars, and it will also compile your code which helps to ensure that things are minimally compatible at least.

But the core issue here is that the plugin's `CreateRoute.groovy` script is badly broken. It's missing an important include and doesn't come close to calling `createArtifact` correctly. As a workaround until the authors get this fixed, create a script in your app's `scripts` folder called `CreateCamelRoute.groovy` with this content:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsCreateArtifacts')

target(createCamelRoute: "Creates a new Camel Route.") {
    createArtifact(type: 'Route', path: 'grails-app/routes', name: argsMap.params?.get(0) ?: 'Example', suffix: 'Route')
}

setDefaultTarget(createCamelRoute)
```

It's intentionally named differently from the original because if Grails finds two with the same name it asks which one to use. This way you can just run

```
grails create-camel-route com.foo.bar.OrderListener
```

and it will work. Note that I changed the example a bit to include a package - always use packages :)

Comment: Thanks @Burt Beckwith - I appreciate the time and help with this, but the fact that the plugin is so buggy right off the bat, combined with the fact that the codebase hasn't changed in 5 months leave me wanting to run away from this plugin kicking and screaming. I think I'll figure out another way to start a Camel route from a background/worker thread. **Any ideas?** Thanks again!

Comment: One would be to contact the developers and see if they are still active. If you feel like nobody uses something you created you're typically not highly motivated to update it :)  Another option is to borrow some of the code that works (be sure to respect the requirements of their chosen license wrt attribution, etc.) And of course you can always just do the same thing you would do in a non-Grails app - integrate Camel according to their docs.